# Is there such a thing as a 'nested find' in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, include, nested, conditional-statements

I've got the hang of nested includes—they're great for performance—but what I'd really like is a 'nested find'. What's the best way to achieve something like:

```
@matchingProducts = Batch.find(:all,
                               :conditions => 'product.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%",
                               :include => :product)
```

As you can see, `Product` is a nested attribute of `Batch`, but I want to find a batch based on `Product.name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 I would use the AREL syntax:

```
@matches = Batch.where('product.name LIKE ?', "search").includes(:product)
```

Comment: Thanks, this reply sort me out, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea was right, you can do `matchingProducts = Batch.find(:all, :include => 'products', :conditions => ["products.name LIKE ?", whatever_you_want], :order => order_as_you_want)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've reworked my code based on your example but no luck.  Please could you clarify what the significant difference in your code vs. mine is?  Is it the use of 'products' instead of :product, or something else?

Comment: I used the table name 'products' instead of the symbol :product and then used it as condition in a sql query. This is the difference. The above code work right for me. What's the error you get when execute the find?

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, much appreciated.  The error I get is, "Association named 'products' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?", but that's when I come to render the results (btw, I'm also trying to combine this with will_paginate, but wanted to simplify my original question).